# Prove using the rule of inference: ∀x (L(x)→ F(x)) and ∃x (L(x) ∧ ¬C(x)) imply ∃x(F(x) ∧ ¬C(x))

Tags: logic, proof-writing, computer-science, predicate-logic

Prove using the rules of inference that the premises ∀x (L(x)→ F(x)) and ∃x (L(x) ∧ ¬C(x)) imply the conclusion ∃x(F(x) ∧ ¬C(x)).

I'm having trouble on getting to the conclusion.

What I have so far is:
1. ∀x (L(x)→ F(x))   Hypoth
2. L(c)→ F(c)        Universal instantiation
3. ∃x (L(x) ∧ ¬C(x)) Hypoth
4. L(c)∧ ~C(x)       Existential instantiation

Answer (score 4):

> 1. ∀x (L(x)→ F(x))   Hypoth
> 2. L(c)→ F(c)        Universal instantiation
> 3. ∃x (L(x) ∧ ¬C(x)) Hypoth
> 4. L(c)→ ~C(x)       Existential instantiation

You cannot instantiate an existential to an arbitrary instance. Rather perform the existential instantiation first, then instantiate the universal to that *non-arbitrary* witness.

Also keep the goal in mind.   You will wish to finally perform an existential generalisation to discharge some witness, so of course you will need to assume one first.

$$\begin{array}{r|l:ll}
1 & \forall x~(L(x)\to F(x)) &&\text{Hypothesis} \\
2 & \exists x~(L(x)\wedge\neg C(x)) &&\text{Hypothesis} \\ \hline
3 & \quad L(c)\wedge \neg C(c) &2, [x\backslash c]& \text{Existential Instantiation}\\
4 & \quad L(c)\to F(c) &1 , [x\backslash c]& \text{Universal Instantiation to witness} \\ \hline
\vdots & \quad \vdots & &\text{(stuff happens)} \\
8 & \quad F(c)\wedge\neg C(c) & & \text{(reasons)} \\
9 & \exists x~(F(x)\wedge \neg C(x)) & 8, [c\backslash x] & \text{Existential Generalisation}
\end{array}$$

Fill in the missing details.

Comment: Good answer! I particularly enjoy the "stuff happens"! :)